# Can't get rid of vertical background color

Tags: graphics, color

I am trying to use `GraphicsGrid`, the background option is set to white, as well as for the separate graphs. But there are still grey stripes. What is the reason for these? And how can I get rid of them?

[image]

```
aa = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}, Background -> White, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Background -> White]];

tttt = Table[Sin[i], {i, -1, 1, 0.1}];

xxxx = Table[i, {i, -1, 1, 0.1}];

Zusammen = Transpose[{xxxx, tttt}];

TestFig =  ListPlot[Zusammen, Background -> White, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Background -> White]];

Tableees = {{-5.51, 2851.82}, {-5.22, 2851.88}, {-4.93,         2851.94}, {-4.64, 2852.01}, {-4.34, 2852.07}, {-4.05,         2852.12}, {-3.76, 2852.18}, {-3.47, 2852.23}, {-3.18,         2852.28}, {-2.89, 2852.32}, {-2.6, 2852.36}, {-2.31,         2852.39}, {-2.02, 2852.42}, {-1.72, 2852.44}, {-1.43,         2852.45}, {-1.14, 2852.47}, {-0.85, 2852.47}, {-0.56,         2852.47}, {-0.27, 2852.47}, {0.02, 2852.46}, {0.32,         2852.46}, {0.61, 2852.45}, {0.9, 852.44}, {1.19, 2852.43}, {1.48,         2852.42}, {1.77, 2852.41}, {2.06, 2852.41}, {2.35,         2852.41}, {2.64, 2852.41}, {2.94, 2852.41}, {3.23,         2852.42}, {3.52, 2852.42}, {3.81, 2852.43}, {4.1, 2852.45}, {4.39,         2852.46}, {4.68, 2852.48}, {4.97, 2852.5}, {5.26,         2852.51}, {5.56, 2852.53}, {5.85, 2852.55}, {6.21, 2852.56}, {6.5,         2852.57}, {6.8, 2852.58}, {7.08, 2852.59}, {7.38, 2852.6}, {7.67,         2852.6}, {7.96, 2852.61}, {8.25, 2852.61}, {8.54,         2852.61}, {8.83, 2852.62}, {9.12, 2852.62}, {9.42,         2852.63}, {9.71, 2852.63}, {10., 2852.64}, {10.29, 
    2852.65}, {10.58, 2852.67}, {10.87, 2852.68}, {11.16,         2852.69}, {11.45, 2852.7}, {11.74, 2852.71}, {12.04,         2852.72}, {12.33, 2852.72}, {12.62, 2852.73}, {12.91,         2852.73}, {13.2, 2852.74}, {13.49, 2852.74}, {13.78,         2852.75}, {14.07, 2852.76}, {14.36, 2852.77}, {14.66,         2852.78}, {14.95, 2852.79}, {15.24, 2852.8}, {15.53,         2852.8}, {15.82, 2852.81}, {16.11, 2852.82}, {16.4,         2852.82}, {16.7, 2852.83}, {16.99, 2852.83}, {17.28,         2852.84}, {17.57, 2852.84}, {17.86, 2852.85}, {18.15, 
    2852.85}, {18.44, 2852.86}, {18.73, 2852.86}, {19.02,         2852.87}, {19.32, 2852.88}, {19.61, 2852.88}, {19.9,         2852.89}, {20.19, 2852.9}, {20.48, 2852.91}, {20.77,         2852.91}, {21.06, 2852.92}, {21.35, 2852.93}, {21.65,         2852.93}, {21.94, 2852.94}, {22.23, 2852.95}, {22.52, 
    2852.96}, {22.81, 2852.96}, {23.1, 2852.97}, {23.39,         2852.97}, {23.68, 2852.98}, {23.97, 2852.98}, {24.27,         2852.99}, {24.56, 2852.99}, {24.85, 2853.}, {25.14,         2853.01}, {25.43, 2853.01}, {25.72, 2853.02}, {26.01,         2853.03}, {26.3, 2853.03}, {26.59, 2853.04}, {26.89,         2853.04}, {27.18, 2853.05}, {27.47, 2853.06}, {27.76,         2853.06}, {28.05, 2853.07}, {28.34, 2853.08}, {28.63,         2853.08}, {28.93, 2853.09}, {29.22, 2853.1}, {29.51,         2853.1}, {29.8, 2853.11}, {30.09, 2853.11}, {30.38,         2853.12}, {30.67, 2853.13}, {30.96, 2853.13}, {31.25,         2853.14}, {31.55, 2853.14}, {31.84, 2853.14}, {32.13,         2853.15}, {32.42, 2853.15}, {32.71, 2853.16}, {33.,         2853.17}, {33.29, 2853.17}, {33.59, 2853.18}, {33.87, 
    2853.18}, {34.17, 2853.19}, {34.46, 2853.19}, {34.75,         2853.2}, {35.04, 2853.21}, {35.33, 2853.22}, {35.62,         2853.23}, {35.91, 2853.23}, {36.2, 2853.24}, {36.5,         2853.25}, {36.79, 2853.25}, {37.08, 2853.26}, {37.37,         2853.26}, {37.66, 2853.27}, {37.95, 2853.28}, {38.24,         2853.28}, {38.53, 2853.29}, {38.82, 2853.29}, {39.12,         2853.3}, {39.41, 2853.3}, {39.7, 2853.31}, {39.99,         2853.32}, {40.28, 2853.32}, {40.57, 2853.33}, {40.86,         2853.33}, {41.15, 2853.34}, {41.45, 2853.35}, {41.74, 
    2853.35}, {42.03, 2853.36}, {42.32, 2853.37}, {42.61,         2853.38}, {42.9, 2853.38}, {43.19, 2853.39}, {43.48,         2853.4}, {43.78, 2853.41}, {44.07, 2853.42}, {44.36,         2853.43}, {44.65, 2853.43}, {44.94, 2853.44}, {45.23,         2853.45}, {45.52, 2853.46}, {45.81, 2853.47}, {46.11,         2853.48}, {46.4, 2853.48}, {46.69, 2853.49}, {46.98,         2853.5}, {47.27, 2853.51}, {47.56, 2853.51}, {47.85,         2853.52}, {48.14, 2853.53}, {48.43, 2853.54}, {48.73,         2853.55}, {49.02, 2853.55}, {49.31, 2853.56}, {49.6, 
    2853.56}, {49.89, 2853.57}, {50.18, 2853.57}, {50.47,         2853.58}, {50.77, 2853.59}, {51.05, 2853.59}, {51.35,         2853.6}, {51.64, 2853.6}, {51.93, 2853.61}, {52.22,         2853.62}, {52.51, 2853.62}, {52.8, 2853.63}, {53.09,         2853.64}, {53.39, 2853.65}, {53.68, 2853.65}, {53.97,         2853.66}, {54.26, 2853.67}, {54.55, 2853.68}, {54.84,         2853.69}, {55.13, 2853.7}, {55.42, 2853.7}, {55.72,         2853.71}, {56.01, 2853.72}, {56.37, 2853.72}, {56.66,         2853.73}, {56.95, 2853.74}, {57.24, 2853.74}, {57.53, 
    2853.75}, {57.83, 2853.76}, {58.12, 2853.77}, {58.41,         2853.77}, {58.7, 2853.78}, {58.99, 2853.79}, {59.28,         2853.79}, {59.57, 2853.8}, {59.86, 2853.81}, {60.16,         2853.82}, {60.45, 2853.83}, {60.74, 2853.84}, {61.03, 2853.84}};

BBBBBB = ListPlot[Tableees, Background -> White, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Background -> White]];



 GraphicsGrid[{{TestFig, aa}, {BBBBBB, aa}, {aa, aa}}, 
 Background -> White]
```

And the output is like this, all fine, except Big Tables.
[image]

---

**Edit (not by the original poster)**

Quite possibly, the issue is instigated by the use of a non-default stylesheet like the Report/StandardReport stylesheet. Those who want to reproduce the described problem should set their notebook's stylesheet using the Format>Stylesheet menu to this stylesheet

Minimal example of code to reproduce issues:

```
CreateDocument[

 GraphicsGrid[
  List /@ Table[  ListPlot[RandomReal[1, 100], Background -> White, 
     ImageSize -> 200],
  {a, 1, 2}]], 
 StyleDefinitions -> FrontEnd`FileName[{"Report"}, "StandardReport.nb", 
   CharacterEncoding -> "WindowsANSI"]
]
```

Comment: please add the code that generates these graphs. This would help us pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Added example code.

Comment: Your figure seems to suggest that you exported the grid to PDF. Do you see the grey stripes in *Mathematica* as well, or just in the PDF file? Also, we can't really run your code because we don't have the definition of your variables. Do you think you could reduce it to a minimal example?

Comment: This code does not help us, since you don't provide `Name`, `FirstDer`, etc. It would be much better, also for you, if you could create a minimal working example, just to show where the problem is. I assume the problem persists even if you plot simply `Plot[Sin[x],{x,-1,1}]`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I see the grey stripes in Mathematica too.

Comment: Lucifer, why do you specify `ImageSize` twice in your `GraphicsGrid` command? I imagine that one of the two will end up being ignored.

Comment: So I have updated the question, added the minimal working example. I don't have problems with Plot[Sin[x]] or ListPlot (see example), but when I try to plot the data I want, I see these grey stripes and have no idea why they are there.

Comment: Is the background in your notebook set to a color that is not white? Can you check what is selected in the menu "Format"->"Background color"? and in the Options Inspector for your notebook (search for option name "background")? What version of MMA are you using?

Comment: I don't see this on Mac. It looks like this is an operating-system dependent bug. Are you using Linux?

Comment: You can get things like this if you use a non-default stylesheet for your notebook. The Report/StandardReport stylesheet for instance, has problems like this. The OP's stylesheet looks similar. @kuba This is real problem in the definition of these stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem for a long time, and it's associated with using a non-standard style sheet. It looks like you're using report. I found that if you revert to default, and put the following code at the start of your notebook it reproduces something like report but with white backgrounds for the output:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
StyleDefinitions -> 
Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
Cell[StyleData["Notebook"], Background -> LightBrown], 
Cell[StyleData["Input"], Background -> RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1], 
CellFrame -> {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
CellMargins -> {{60, Inherited}, {0, 5}}], 
Cell[StyleData["Output"], Background -> GrayLevel[1], 
CellMargins -> {{60, Inherited}, {5, 0}}, 
CellFrame -> {{1, 1}, {1, 0}}], 
Cell[StyleData["Section"], Background -> LightBrown, 
CellMargins -> {{Inherited, Inherited}, {5, 0}}]}, 
StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]
```

I guess this doesn't address your problem directly, but it might be sufficient for your purposes.